# How can I adjust the position of the textalignment in placeholder and the main text separately in swift?

Tags: swift, alignment, placeholder

How can I set the `textAlignment` of the placeholder in the right and the `textAlignment` of the main text in the left in `UITextField` in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UITextField` to [natural](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nstextalignment/1533940-natural) `textAlignment` in Swift. In Interface Builder that's the alignment on the right with the dashes:

[image]